# Как с помощью JS менять стили в брейкпоинтах медиазапроса?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, media-queries, breakpoint

Как с помощью JS менять стили в брейкпоинтах медиазапроса? Конкретно необходимо поменять width объекту только в разрешении 320. Чтобы он не менялся глобально.

Comment: Больше подробностей бы: что есть, что хотите, что пытались.

Comment: Есть буллит в слайдере swiper размером 15 на 15 пикселей, необходимо чтобы на 320 размер был 10 на 10 пикселей. Пытался переопределить с помощью медазапроса на 320 но не сработало.